# Excel to Tally Import with multiples Cost categories

Tags: import-from-excel, data-import, data-integration, tally, excel-template

I want to import Journal vouchers in Tally. For each ledger in the voucher, I need to specify multiple Cost categories and against each Cost category, I need multiple Cost centres.

Here's an example.

Ledger named **Ledger-1**

- Manufacturing **Cost Category-1**
- Cost Centre1 - Rs 500
- Cost Centre2 - Rs 300
- Cost Centre3 - Rs 200
- Location **Cost Category-2**
- Cost Centre1 - Rs 400
- Cost Centre2 - Rs 600

As you can see, there are **two** Cost Categories and then multiple cost centres against each Cost category. I am looking for an excel to tally import tool or Tally XML tags which can import this data in Tally.

Please specify the Excel template name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import data from Excel to Tally in several ways. You can create XML file using any free tool and import it in Tally under import of data option. You can also use the udiMagic online template builder to generate a new Excel template for import in Tally.

Use the udiMagic template named "**Vouchers-V10-Financial-transactions-Advanced.xls**" provided with the udiMagic software to import Journal vouchers with multiple Cost Categories and Cost Centres.

*Excel sheet details*
Column L - specify the Cost Category details
Column M - Specify the Cost Centre details

To get the Tally XML tags for uploading Journal vouchers with multiple Cost Categories, you must enable the settings as shown underneath.

**udiMagic settings**

1. Start udiMagic Software.
2. Click the **Settings** button and enable the option "**Send XML tag to file**".
3. Next, click the **save** button to save the settings.

**Steps to Import data from Excel to Tally**

1. Start Tally ERP and Open a Company
2. Start udiMagic software
3. Select the option **Excel to Tally**
4. Select the option **Import data into Tally**
5. Click the **Browse** button and select "**Vouchers-V9-Financial-transactions-Advanced.xls**" provided with udiMagic converter
6. Click the **Start** button

The above steps will import data into Tally. In addition, it will generate a file name "**xmltags.xml**" which contains the XML request sent to Tally. The XML file is automatically generated in the folder where udiMagic is installed.

Excel to Tally : https://www.rtslink.com

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to import vouchers from Excel to Tally. You can create XML file can import it in Tally under import of data option. But for that you have to know knowledge of Tally XML tag. Also some online tool is available which it auto create XML from Excel data and directly import it in Tally.

In XLtool there is very simple steps to import Excel data in Tally application.

Follow these steps for import vouchers Excel to Tally

- Enable ODBC port in Tally application.
- Open one Tally application & open only one company.
- In XLTOOL software ​fillup the data in appropriate voucher template.
- Open MY MENU by F1 Key.
- click START button.
- Data will be imported in Tally.
- Download Excel template from - [www.xltally.in](https://www.xltally.in)

**Following are the Tally XML Code tag for Vouchers -**

```
"<TALLYMESSAGE xmlns:UDF=""TallyUDF"">"_
"<VOUCHER VCHTYPE="" ACTION="Create">"
<VOUCHERTYPENAME></VOUCHERTYPENAME>
<VOUCHERNUMBER></VOUCHERNUMBER>
<REFERENCE></REFERENCE>
<REFERENCEDATE></REFERENCEDATE>
<DATE></DATE>
<PARTYLEDGERNAME></PARTYLEDGERNAME>
<ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST
<REMOVEZEROENTRIES>No</REMOVEZEROENTRIES>
<ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>No</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
<LEDGERFROMITEM>No</LEDGERFROMITEM>
<LEDGERNAME>Sachin</LEDGERNAME>
<AMOUNT> 500</AMOUNT>
</ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
</VOUCHER>
</TALLYMESSAGE>"
```

End Sub